# how to specify in case of an Android local development?

Tags: android, local

Is there a way to tell Android we are developing and testing the application locally ? so I can write something like that in the code to execute specific code that has to be executed in case of a local development vs when the application is intended to be deployed and fetch the right remote data :

```
if (LOCALLY) {
  MyLocalTools.xdebugIntegration();
  ...
}
...
```

And when the application is to be shared, i just have to turn a global option to mute all the local code ?

Comment: how about using the `Junit` etc testing module to do the testing from local data?

Comment: I'm aware of the existence of `Junit` but because this is a small personal app and I prefer using the debugger and use `AVC` to simulate users' interaction with the app. Second point is I am debugging php using xdebug and when programming locally I need to load the page using my local server ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use build flavor and build variants.

In your build.gradle you can define some flavors like follows:

```
productFlavors {

        dev {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_URL_BASE", "\"dev.example/rest\""
            applicationId "development.example.app"
        }

        prod {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_URL_BASE", "\"prod.example/rest\""
            applicationId "com.example.app"
        }

    }
```

As you can see we have defined 2 flavor with different variables to use. In my case I have defined two different endpoints for rest services and different application id.

Then on the bottom left of Android Studio you can select which build variant use to launch your app. Build variants are the union of build flavors and build types (defaults build types are debug and release).

In your code you can access variables defined in build.gradle file like follows:

```
BuildConfig.SERVICE_URL_BASE
```

And you can access your build type with of flavor with something like this:

```
BuildConfig.FLAVOR
BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE
```

Using these variables you can implement all the switch you desire

Comment: will these informations be any way included in the final artifact ?

Comment: Yeah and you can use this approach to have all of your build variant variables in your build.gradle file. Obviously you will have only variable value matching your build variant

Comment: when debugging the normal way, how can I switch between a flavor to another ? you see, I have a local and a remote HTTP server for REST Service, now before deploying my app I want to be sure the REST Service on my remote server behaves the same as my local one. productFlavors seems like what I need but how do I switch from one flavor to another one in the debug process ?

Comment: you must rebuild your project. You must open BuildVariants view from bottom left in Android Studio, and there select from menu the desired one for module app. Then relaunch your app and it will use current build variants variables

Answer (score 3):

If by "local development", you mean `debug` builds, and by "intended to be deployed", you mean `release` builds, you can use `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE` to distinguish those [build types](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html), or use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` to distinguish between builds that are debuggable versus those that are not. Or, if you need a particular constant, [use `buildConfigField`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code) to add that custom field to `BuildConfig`.

Product flavors, cited in another answer, are designed for cases where you need two separate release builds (e.g., one with Google's in-app purchasing APIs, one with Amazon's in-app purchasing APIs).

Comment: Product flavors are designed for other usecases but they offers more flexibility IMHO

Comment: @firegloves: There is very little that a product flavor can do in this area that a build type cannot do. Plus, using flavor dimensions for N distinct groups of flavors starts to get cumbersome. Hence, for things that are truly tied to the development lifecycle, I recommend modeling them using build types.

Comment: Ok, thinking well on what you said I agree with you

Comment: @CommonsWare actually I think productFlavors is more appropriate in my case. Maybe i wasn't clear in my question but `productFlavors` will add to both `release` and `debug` a "new mode", this is what I want. For both `release` and `debug` i need to be able to switch between my local and remote HTTP server, `productFlavors` will put some ease in that process.